# MVC 4 Form - how the binding to the controller function is done?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I'm new to MVC 4 (and to GUI in general), and did a tutorial or two, and got some traditional HTMLs to integrate them to MVC new solution.

My question -

I have a MyModel.cs in Models folder.
I have SignUp.cshtml in my Views folder (static tradional html without al HTML helpers..)
I have MyController.cs in my Controllers folder.

1. I added reference to the model (@model XXX.XXX.MyModel)
2. Before the existing form I added @using (Html.BeginForm())...
3. I converted one of the text fields to be in the new way :

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)

now what? how do I pass the form details to the conteroller?
tried to have

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()...

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(MyModel model1)
```

but the functions are not invoked after I submit the form...I miss something here (probably in my understanding of the binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** If you are not using **HTML Helpers** make sure that every name of every **input** control in you **View** matches the name of the properties from your model, or the Default `ModelBinder` will not be able to build the model back in the server;

MyModel.cs:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public string Property1 {get; set;}
   public string Property2 {get; set;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="Property1" id="Property1" />
<input type="text" name="Property2" id="Property2" />
```

**2)** You must provide the action and others parameters to Html.BeginForm, looks like thats your problem, the form can't find the action to post, so:

```
@using(BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod /*POST or GET*/))
{
   //Forms controls here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds like I'm pretty close but still get the 404 of /MyController/Create. I did like you suggested and matched the name and ID in .cshtml to the property name in Model class. Is the "CREATE" stands for the method name to invoke? and the "ControllerName" is the controller.cs class?

Comment: You must provide ControllerName without the Controller, hows you are calling the BeginForm? Update the answear with the view code as well.

Comment: BINGO (I removed the controller suffix)!!! it's always the little things right? thanks! @Jaimin - I'll explore yours too soon

Answer (score 1):

Try with this,

**Model**

```
 public class RegisterModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone is required.")]
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model XXX.XXX.RegisterModel


  @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FrmIndex" }))
        { 
           <div>

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)

            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address)
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNo)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNo)
              </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Save" style="float: left;" id="btnSave" title="btn" name="ButtonType" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Create(RegisterModel model)
    {
         return View();
    }
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(RegisterModel model)
    {
      if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid) // check to see if any users are missing required fields. if not...
        {
            if (model.ID != 0)
            {
                UpdateRegister(model);
            }
            else
            {

                InsertRegister(model);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! tried that and got 404 error on requested URL: /MyController/Create.   I need to create a new View? what if I just want to do some internal DB update and return to the home page? should I change the parameters you suggested? I thought Create was the method name reference..

Comment: You want to pass textbox `FirstName`  value to controller right?

Comment: Hi i just update my code with example try like this and it's perfectly working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the model the first time, as it's just an empty structure then, which is referenced in the view:

```
    [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Create()
    {
         return View();
    }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(RegisterModel model)
    {
      if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid) // check to see if any users are missing required fields. if not...
        {
            if (model.ID != 0)
            {
                UpdateRegister(model);
            }
            else
            {

                InsertRegister(model);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```